# CKEditor - Reflect styles, also those with complex selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, ckeditor

I use `config.ContentsCss` to load the live site's styles into the editor:

`config.contentsCss = ['../css/reset.css','../css/screen.css'];`

**But**, many elements have more complex selectors, such as `#content h2`, and since the editor handles only elements **inside** `<div id="content"> »» WHAT THE EDITOR SEES «« </div>`

**Example** - H2 elements:

Inside `screen.css` I have this selector:

```
#content h2 { color: #76828A !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
```

In the live page it does show the element correctly, but since the editor loads only the text **inside** `#content`, it doesn't being shown correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, I replied to the question when posted in the CKEditor forums: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=25962